# Display green Tick icon next to the Input filed after the text box focused

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want a green tick icon near to the text box if the text box is focused. If the text box is not focused i want to display a red cross icon near to text box using onblur() function.Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need JavaScript for this, as CSS will work perfectly fine. Try out the following code:

```
<apex:page >
    <style>
        .checkbox + .check-after .showCheck, .checkbox:focus + .check-after .noCheck {
        display: none;
        }
        .checkbox:focus + .check-after .showCheck, .checkbox + .check-after .noCheck {
        display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText styleClass="checkbox" />
        <span class="check-after">
            <span class="showCheck"><apex:image url="/img/msg_icons/confirm16.png"/></span>
            <span class="noCheck"><apex:image url="/img/msg_icons/error16.png"/></span>
        </span>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Very nice, +1 from me.

Comment: Cool solution @sfdcfox

Answer (score 2):

The sort of JavaScript you could use:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">

<apex:form>
    <apex:inputField
            value="{!Contact.FirstName}"
            onfocus="display('none', 'inline')"
            onblur="display('inline', 'none')"
            />
    <div id="green">green cross icon goes here</div>
    <div id="red">red cross icon goes here</div>
</apex:form>

<script>
function display(red, green) {
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = red;
    document.getElementById("green").style.display = green;
}
display('inline', 'none');
</script>

</apex:page>
```